# Probability of exact k occurence within a fixed waiting time

Tags: exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

Assume that the waiting time for each event follows the exponential distribution with the parameter $\lambda$.
Let $\tau_{i,j}$ denote the waiting time between $i$th event and $j$th event.
For a fixed duration $T$, what is the probability $P(\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}<T \text{ and }\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}+\tau_{3,4}>T)$? That is, Events 2 and 3 happened within time T after the occurrence of Event 1, but Event 4 has not.

I am stuck in finding the joint pdf of $\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}<T$, and  $\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}+\tau_{3,4}>T$.

Let $X=\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}$ and $Y=\tau_{3,4}$, then its equivalent to find $P(X<T \text{ and } Y>T-X)$, here $X$ is a random variable follows the gamma distribution.

If I have the joint pdf, then I can compute $P(X<T \text{ and } Y>T-X)$ as follows:
$\int_{0}^{T}\int_{T-x}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,dy\,dx$.

How to find the $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ in this case?

Comment: Assuming independence of waiting times, $P(\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}\le T)$ would be the CDF of a gamma or Erlang distribution with shape $2$ (it is the sum of two exponential distributions) and a closed form.  $P( \tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}+\tau_{3,4}\le T)$ would be the CDF of a different gamma or Erlang distribution with shape $3$ also with a closed form.  You are looking for the difference between these.

Comment: "Event 1,2,3 happened in T" is not quite correct: instead "Events 2 and 3 happened within time T of event 1"

Comment: Hi Henry, you are right. I need to be more precise. How to quantify the difference between two different Erlang random variable, cause they might be dependent.

Comment: They are highly dependent: $\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}+\tau_{3,4}\le T$ can only happen when  $\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}\le T$ happens.  That is why you can subtract the probabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming independence of waiting times, the joint density for three random variables $(\tau_{1,2},\tau_{2,3},\tau_{3,4})$ when they are positive is the product of their individual densities $$f(\tau_{1,2},\tau_{2,3},\tau_{3,4})=\lambda^3 e^{-\lambda(\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}+\tau_{3,4})}.$$

The tricky part is setting the limits of integration.  I think you are looking for

$$\begin{align}&P(\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}<T \text{ and }\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}+\tau_{3,4}>T) \\=&\int_{\tau_{1,2}=0}^T\int_{\tau_{2,3}=0}^{T-\tau_{1,2}}\int_{\tau_{3,4}=T-\tau_{1,2}-\tau_{2,3}}^{\infty} f(\tau_{1,2},\tau_{2,3},\tau_{3,4})\, d\tau_{3,4}\,d\tau_{2,3}\,d\tau_{1,2}\\ =& \frac12(\lambda T)^2 e^{-\lambda T}\end{align}$$

This is a probability, but happens to be proportional to the expression for the density for a gamma or Erlang distribution of shape $3$ (and identical when $\lambda=1$).

Alternatively you could see this as the difference between two CDFs of gamma or Erlang distributions with different results: you want $P(\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}\le T) - P(\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}+\tau_{3,4}\le T)$, with subtraction possible since the latter can only happen when the former does.

As you would hope, these provide the same result.  Plotting the two curves with R gives a perfect match.

```
lambda=1
curve(1/2 * (lambda*x)^2 * exp(-lambda*x), from=0, to=10, 
      xlab="lambda T", lwd=2, col="blue")
curve(pgamma(x,2,lambda) - pgamma(x,3,lambda), from=0, to=10, 
      add=TRUE, col="red")
abline(h=0)
```

[image: probability]

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks a lot. The triple integration is exactly what I am looking for, I was stuck on what f( ) should be, but now I get it!

Comment: What if there is another Event 5, which can happen only after Event 3, it's like there is a branch after Event 3, I am trying to follow the steps you suggest to compute $P(\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}<T, \tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}+\tau_{3,4}>T, \tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}+\tau_{3,5}>T )$, so I add one more integral as 
$\int_{\tau_{1,2}=0}^T\int_{\tau_{2,3}=0}^{T-\tau_{1,2}}\int_{\tau_{3,4}=T-\tau_{1,2}-\tau_{2,3}}^{\infty}\int_{\tau_{3,5}=T-\tau_{1,2}-\tau_{2,3}}^{\infty} f(\tau_{1,2},\tau_{2,3},\tau_{3,4},\tau_{3,5})\, d\tau_{3,5},d\tau_{3,4}\,d\tau_{2,3}\,d\tau_{1,2}$, but the result looks weird

Comment: That would change your model, which would no longer be a Poisson process. So really a different question.  If you wanted to use a similar method, you would want to consider the distribution of $\tau_{1,2}+\tau_{2,3}+\tau_{3,m}$ where $m$ is the earlier of events $4$ and $5$.  Perhaps  $\tau_{3,m}$ would have an exponential distribution with rate $2 \lambda$.  A quick unchecked attempt suggests to me that you could be looking at something like $\frac12(\lambda T)^2 e^{-\lambda T}$  $e^{-2\lambda T}+(\lambda T-1) e^{-\lambda T}$.  You could check for particular $\lambda$ and $T$ by simulation